# ParTraverse Not a Value of NonEmptyList

Tags: scala, cats-effect

I am following the instructions on the cats IO website to run a sequence of effects in parallel:

My code looks like:

```scala
    val maybeNonEmptyList: Option[NonEmptyList[Urls]] = NonEmptyList.fromList(urls)

    val maybeDownloads: Option[IO[NonEmptyList[Either[Error, Files]]]] = maybeNonEmptyList map { urls =>
      urls.parTraverse(url => downloader(url))
    }
```

But I get a compile time error saying:

```scala
value parTraverse is not a member of cats.data.NonEmptyList[Urls]
[error]       urls.parTraverse(url => downloader(url))
```

I have imported the following:

```scala
import cats.data.{EitherT, NonEmptyList}
import cats.effect.{ContextShift, IO, Timer}
import cats.implicits._
import cats.syntax.parallel._
```

and also i have the following implicits:

```scala
    implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)
    implicit val timer: Timer[IO]     = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.global)
```

Why do i still get the problem?

Comment: Remove this `import cats.syntax.parallel._` the **implicits** import brings everything into scope, adding another one will create ambiguities.

Comment: Thanks bro - that did it!

Comment: so, if you import two times the same implicit it becomes ambiguous. So, moat libraries provide how to import implicits granually or all at once, choose the style you prefer, but stick to one.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because the implicit enrichment is being imported twice, so it becomes ambiguous

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.syntax.parallel._
```

As of recent versions of cats, `implicits` imports are never required, only `syntax`

The recommended pattern is to do only `import cats.syntax.all._`