# What is the exact import for resolving triple equals in Cats?

Tags: scala

What is the exact import for the triple equals?

Before I was importing "cats.implicits._" and it was working fine but I can't do that anymore as it causes ambiguities with other imports.

Comment: If you just import `cats.implicits._` you should be fine. - Anyways, the import you need is `cats.syntax.eq._` and ensure the instance of **Eq** for the type you want to compare is in scope.

Comment: bro I can't because of  https://stackoverflow.com/q/60280539/10290548

Comment: What I did was: import cats.implicits._
//import cats.instances.future._
//import cats.syntax.parallel._

Comment: I took out future and parallel and replaced all with cats.implicits._

Comment: If that worked, I would suggest you to close this question. If not, please edit it with all details.

Answer (score 0):

Triple equals resides in package `cats.evidence`

https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/evidence/package.scala

Moreover, some of its instances reside in `cats.evidence.Is`:

https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/evidence/Is.scala

Then, probably `cats.evidence._` `cats.evidence.Is._` would be enough.

The general way of figuring out which implicit instance is used by function (at least in Intellij Idea) is `Ctrl+Shift+P` for arguments, and `Ctrl+Shift+Q` for implicit conversions.

Comment: You are confusing the value safe equality `===` with the type equality `Is`.